Vitest: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'once')
I am trying to setup a unittest using vitest based on a reactjs project.
This is my unittest code from Gamesettings.test.tsx:
import { it, expect, describe } from 'vitest';
import {screen, render} from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/vitest';
import GameSettingsPage from '../pages/gamesettings';

describe('swapPlayers', () => {
    it('Check player if swaps', () => {
        render(<GameSettingsPage />);
        screen.debug();
    })
})

This is the component im trying to test (gamesettings.tsx):
import {
  Page,
} from 'framework7-react';

const GameSettingsPage = () => {
  return (
    <Page></Page>
  );
};

export default GameSettingsPage;

This is my vitest.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
})

Im getting the following error:
src/tests/Gamesettings.test.tsx > swapPlayers > Check player if swaps
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'once')
 ❯ f7ready node_modules/framework7-react/shared/f7.js:68:14
 ❯ attachEvents node_modules/framework7-react/shared/use-tab.js:15:5
 ❯ node_modules/framework7-react/shared/use-tab.js:26:5
 ❯ commitHookEffectListMount node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23150:26
 ❯ commitLayoutEffectOnFiber node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23273:15
 ❯ commitLayoutMountEffects_complete node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24688:9
 ❯ commitLayoutEffects_begin node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24674:7
 ❯ commitLayoutEffects node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24612:3
 ❯ commitRootImpl node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26823:5
 ❯ commitRoot node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26682:5


If I shall provide more information, let me know.
How can I solve this?
I would expect that I can unittest the behavior of my component using components from other frameworks.

Is there nobody to know a solution?
